# Site not working in Internet Explorer, working fine in Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla, prompt

I have installed my joomla website in the root directory. It is working fine in Google chrome and Mozilla, but when I open in Internet Explorer it shows a dialog box to open or save a file.

Comment: can you give a bit more information? Does this happen in any other situation or just when you visit the homepage, when is that dialog meant to be displayed? What code have you got etc?

Comment: What server (software) are you installing this on?

Comment: When i visit the home page or any other page ..it gives me this error....the dialog box says...suppose my url is byakuwait.com...it says....Do you want to open or save file coming from bya_kuwait.com......I am using Windows Server

Comment: did you install the Joomla package straight from the Joomla website or a kick start package from a template company? I'm no expert with .htaccess but I think it might be because of this. Also, what version of IE are you using?

Comment: installed the joomla package direct from the godaddy.com(hosting)and i m using IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing an IE compatibility plugin in your website. You can find them online

Comment: Thanks for the concern...but no change

Comment: The problem was solved..I forgot to post it...As I was using newsfeeds   the problem was in xml file format...I took another module and it worked!!!